# Wix File property with user selected directory

Tags: wix, installation, wix3

I am trying to install a windows service using wix but I can't seem to point the file for the service to the user selected install directory.

```
<Component Id="MyServiceInstaller_ServiceControl" Guid="B72CAA3F-F2DB-48D2-90DD-061209AB2CE5" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
        <CreateFolder />
        <File Id='MyServiceEXE' Name='MyService.exe' DiskId='1' Source='[INSTALLDIR]MyService.exe'  KeyPath='yes'/>
        <ServiceInstall Id="MyServiceInstaller_ServiceInstall"
            Type="ownProcess"
            Vital="yes"
            Name="My Service"                    
            DisplayName="My Service"
            Description="This will make windows services great again!"
            Start="auto"
            Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
            ErrorControl="ignore"
            Interactive="no" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceInstaller_ServiceInstall" 
            Name="My Service"
            Stop="both"
            Remove="uninstall"
            Wait="yes" />               
    </Component>
```

The issue seems to be when I use any [PROPERTY] directory I get the following error.

> error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file
>   '[INSTALLDIR]MyService.exe'.

How do I tell Wix to use the installation folder the user selected as the path for the service?

Answer (score 1):

`File/@Source` points to the file in your build environment. `Component/@Directory` tells Windows Installer where the file should be installed. That controls the file used to install and control the service.